# access to different data via c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a manager, which provides access via templates to containers that store different types of data.

First of all, i made base manager class for storing different type of data

```
template <typename T>

class BaseMapManager{
public:
T add(T element, std::string name);

T remove(T element);
T remove(std::string name);
T remove(unsigned int id);

T get(std::string name);    
T get(unsigned int id);

BaseMapManager() { id = 0; };
~BaseMapManager() { nameMap.clear(); idMap.clear(); };

protected:
    std::map<std::string, T> nameMap;
    std::map<unsigned int, T> idMap;

//each element of type T gets new unique id
unsigned int id;

//hide it
BaseMapManager(const BaseMapManager&) {};
BaseMapManager& operator=(const BaseMapManager&) {};
};
```

Then i made my concrete manager, which had to store 3 types of baseMapManagers:

```
class ResourceManager{
public:
    //creates singleton
    static ResourceManager* init(){
        static ResourceManager singleton;
        return &singleton;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void load_resource(std::string path, std::string name){
        get_map<std::shared_ptr<T>>().add(std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(path, name), name);
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> get_resource(std::string name){
        get_map<T>().get(name);
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> get_resource(unsigned int id){
        get_map<T>().get(id);
    }


private:
    BaseMapManager<std::shared_ptr<AnimationResource> > animationMap;
    BaseMapManager<std::shared_ptr<ImageResource> > imageMap;
    BaseMapManager<std::shared_ptr<FontResource> > fontMap;

    template <typename T>
    BaseMapManager<T>& get_map(){
        if (std::is_same<T, std::shared_ptr<AnimationResource> >() == true) return animationMap;
        if (std::is_same<T, std::shared_ptr<ImageResource> >() == true) return imageMap;
        if (std::is_same<T, std::shared_ptr<FontResource> >() == true) return fontMap;
    };
};
```

and now i got this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BOSS, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>d:\programming\github projects\boss\boss\new\resourcemanager\resourcemanager.h(43): 
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'BaseMapManager<T>' to 'BaseMapManager<T> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::shared_ptr<ImageResource>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=std::shared_ptr<AnimationResource>
1>          ]
1>          d:\programming\github projects\boss\boss\new\resourcemanager\resourcemanager.h(21) : see reference to function template instantiation 'BaseMapManager<T> &ResourceManager::get_map<std::shared_ptr<_Ty>>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::shared_ptr<AnimationResource>,
1>              _Ty=AnimationResource
1>          ]
1>          d:\programming\github projects\boss\boss\new\main.cpp(17) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void ResourceManager::load_resource<AnimationResource>(std::string,std::string)' being compiled
1>d:\programming\github projects\boss\boss\new\resourcemanager\resourcemanager.h(44): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'BaseMapManager<T>' to 'BaseMapManager<T> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::shared_ptr<FontResource>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=std::shared_ptr<AnimationResource>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The goal is - providing access to different types on data using template functions like 
`manager->get_resource<AnimationResource>(itsName)` //get it    or
`manager->load_resource<FontResource>(itsPath, itsName)` //add it

Is there a better way to handle this maybe?  Thanks!

Comment: why you use "if (something == true)" instead of "if (something)"?

Comment: Also, if you are only supporting those 3 classes, why not create 3 versions of the template function that support each one instead of using std::is_same?

Comment: 1) I use expressions like (something == true) for clarity
2) Do you mean in case of get_map function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**
The source of your problem seams to be the is_same function not resolving correctly at compile time.
    **/edit**

You can always have template functions that only work with the specified types.

For example:

```
template<>
BaseMapManager<AnimationResource> get_map<AnimationResource>()
{
    return animationMap;
}

template<>
BaseMapManager<ImageResource> get_map<ImageResource>()
{
    return imageMap;
}

template<>
BaseMapManager<FontResource> get_map<FontResource>()
{
    return fontMap;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, it works, i just didnt expect is_same can not work properly. 

I rly tried to provide easy access to data, but now it looks ugly :( isn't? are there a ways to improve my way?

Comment: In my opinion this way is better but your right, it might not be as pretty. But I also keep away from STD:: content (no reason just prefer native or my own way). Glad it works, been a while since I used it :)

Comment: What whould you recommend for defining standart version of template? i mean - anyway i have to make this function - 
template <typename T> BaseMapManager <T> get_map(). dont know which value it has to return in this case

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand. Are you asking for a way of doing functions so that you don't have to write the type for each implementation? If that's what you want the only thing I can think of is using `type_id(T) == type_id(FontResource)` or similar (but it isn't as user friendly/good structure I think). Plus it has a performance hit I think.